# Convert with tshark via command shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to have a `cronjob` convert files with `tshark`.

This is my script so far:

```
files=$(find /home/user/traces/*.pcap -mmin +10 -type f)
echo "$files" | tshark -r - -T ek > '/home/user/traces/converted/'-.json
```

I'm trying to convert files older than 10 minutes, and put them in `converted` folder.

But it fails with:

```
tshark: The standard input isn't a capture file in a format TShark understands.
```

I think the passing of filenames to `tshark` fails, but not sure.

For reference, this single command does work:

```
tshark -r /home/user/traces/trace.pcap -T ek > /home/user/traces/converted/trace.pcap.json
```

**UPDATE**

Seems to work with for loop:

```
files=$(find /home/user/traces/*.pcap -mmin +10 -type f)

for file in $files
do
  echo "processing file: $file"
  tshark -r $file -T ek > "$file.json"
done
```

Comment: `$files` includes files in line by line bases. I believe multiple files cannot be captured in with `echo "$files" | tshark -r -`. how does tshark supports multiple files?

Comment: Ah, needs to loop through... Updated. Thank you, seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$files includes files in line by line bases. I believe multiple files cannot be captured in with `echo "$files" | tshark -r -`.

It seems that you need to have loop

```
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
for f in $files    
do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> -r  `<infile>`
>
> Read packet data from infile, can be any supported capture file format (including gzipped files).  It is possible to use named pipes or stdin (-) here but only with certain (not compressed) capture file formats (in particular: those that can be read
>              without seeking backwards).

TShark does not use its standard input (`-`) to read file a filename but read file contents, like this:

```sh
cat file.pcap | tshark -r - -T ek > "other-file.json"
```

In your case, since you need the output filename to be separate, I would suggest using a loop, like in [this Stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52026/bash-how-to-read-one-line-at-a-time-from-output-of-a-command).

Comment: Maybe avoid the [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: I used it as an example of how to use the standard input from TShark, it is not the way I would do it for a single file but for a file passed through a series of Unix piped commands.